# Parse HTML using BeautifulSoup depending on previous tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML in which I have some tagged text following some titles. Something like this:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some other <b>text</b></p>

<h1>Title 2</h1>
<p>Some <b>text</b></p>
<p>Some text2</p>

<h1>Title 3</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some other <i>text</i></p>
```

(The only fixed thing is the number of titles, the rest can change)

How can I extract with BeautifulSoup all the HTML following each  but before the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pass a regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) `Title \d+` as a [`text` argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and find all titles, then use [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the next two `p` tags:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some other <b>text</b></p>

    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Some <b>text</b></p>
    <p>Some text2</p>

    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some other <i>text</i></p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', text=re.compile('Title \d+')):
    for p in h1.find_next_siblings('p', limit=2):
        print p.text.strip()
```

prints:

```
Some text
Some other text
Some text
Some text2
Some text
Some other text
```

Or, using list-comprehension:

```
print [p.text.strip()
       for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', text=re.compile('Title \d+'))
       for p in h1.find_next_siblings('p', limit=2)]
```

prints:

```
[u'Some text', u'Some other text', u'Some text', u'Some text2', u'Some text', u'Some other text']
```